# 301 Redirect without slash on destination-url

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, seo

i did a website relaunch and now i need 301 redirects to keep my page rank :)

My old website looked like this:

www.domain.com/start/
or www.domain.com/start

New Website looks like this:

www.domain.com/home.html

My Rewrite-Rule looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^start/ /home.html  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^start /home.html [R=301,L]
```

without the slash it redirects to home.html fine, but with start/ it redirects to home.html/ and goes 404..
I read multiple solutions but none worked for me, so your my last hope and im in kind of a hurry, thats why i ask here.

Thank you in advance, Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single rewrite rule. with an optional slash denoted by `\/?`.  Terminate the rewrite rule by a `$` so that /start/foo doesn't also match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^start\/?$ /home.html  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add backslash on second line

```
RewriteRule ^start\/ /home.html  [R=301,L]
```

good luck!